# Calculate date difference and remove the last 8 chars hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, date

I am currently designing a custom report in a treasury management system, need to calculate a difference between 2 dates,

```
{DateDiff(Date1,Date2)}
```

above expression will output like `1234.00:00:00`

but I need to remove the last 8 chars which are `00:00:00`

Not sure what language is used in the custom report builder, I tried below Remove function, but can not get result:

[image]

Comment: What reporting system are you using? Why do you think it's C# if you don't know the language?

Comment: What if you use `DateDiff(Date1.Date, Date2.Date)` which ignores hours?

Comment: The system is called Reval, their implementation team told me the language in the reporting system is C#.

Comment: I hope I can ignore the hours, but the date format is "datetime", it is including the hours, and also output hours.

Comment: I could make a wild guess this is Crystal Reports. Do you want to change the tag on the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is not c#!

Use the substring function to take only the first 4 characters.

```
result = Substring(result, 0, Length(result) - 9)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually the length need to be dynamic, as it is calculated via a date difference, if the difference is large enough, I need to keep over 4 characters.
One of my friend also said it is not C#.

Comment: Changed my answer. Will now use length to remove the last 9 characters from the string

Answer (score -2):

You could use `Split`:

```
string dateDiff = "1234.00:00:00";
string dayDiff = dateDiff.Split('.')[0];

// dayDiff -> 1234
```

Comment: This is not related to C#

Comment: So why the C# tag . and: _the language in the reporting system is C#_?

Comment: The C# tag is wrong. The language is not C#. It appears to have some limited functions that are interpreted by the reporting tool and are named similarly to C# functions.

Comment: thank you all the same, there is no Split function.
I can only use the functions in the screen cap, just remove the first '.' and all the chars after this '.'
like 1234.00:00:00 to 1234
123.00:00:00 to 123

Comment: Yes, it may be not C#, but the system vendor told me it is C#, I selected the most relevant tag, sorry about that.

Comment: OK, then @SteveHarris ' method will do. I tried deleting my answer but that would kill the comments as well.